# why Math.round not worked correctly for me in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math-functions

I have  2 number that I use Math.round to round it,for example I want if my number is 900.20 it rounded to 900.00 and if 12.80 it rounded to 13.
I use Math.round but 900.20 rounded to 910.00 but 12.8 rounded to 13 correctly.

```
var num1=900.20;
var num2=12.80;

var result1=  Math.round(num1.toFixed(2));
var result2=  Math.round(num2.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Math isn't related to jquery.  And toFixed method returns a string. Use parseFloat(result.toFixed (2)); instead.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in snippet?

Comment: @CarlosDelgado parseFloat not worked for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using  `.toFixed()` function ? 
Just use `Math.round()` function and it will work. You don't need to convert it to string.